# how to convey auth token in header with help the fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm need send user data at request to my endpoint (rest api), but gets 401 error only if make request from the js side. If make request from Postman, I get 200 status. I did everything as in the documentation. for reference: make request from Nodejs. Thanks

```
var token = 'Token 897d3c9991952bc715fcf6c3e262e5b3866342';
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append('Authorization', token);
fetch(this.domain + '/v1.0/user/data/', {method: 'GET', headers: myHeaders, mode: 'no-cors'})
.then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        } else {
                throw new Error('error');
        }
  })
```

Comment: Are you sure that it should be `Token` and not `Bearer`?

Comment: What "documentation" ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch Yes, sure. From the postman works fine

Comment: Look at the exact configuration you have in PostMan. Check the details. If this is Basic HTTP Authentication, it should be Basic instead of Token.

Comment: I make from this example: http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2015/10/27/how-to-use-django-rest-frameworks-token-based-authentication

Comment: is token correct? try appending token to url as query param e.g. fetch(this.domain + '/v1.0/user/data/?auth=' + token,

Answer (score 0):

Check this link `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch` or you can use `axios` to make request.

```
const axios = require('axios');
// Make a request for a user with a given ID
axios.get('http://<host>:<port>/<end-point>?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

fetch:

```
// Example POST method implementation:

postData(`http://<host>:<port>/<end-point>`, {answer: 42})
  .then(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))) // JSON-string from `response.json()` call
  .catch(error => console.error(error));

function postData(url = ``, data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
    return fetch(url, {
        method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: "cors", // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
        cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
        credentials: "same-origin", // include, same-origin, *omit
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            // "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
        referrer: "no-referrer", // no-referrer, *client
        body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    })
    .then(response => response.json()); // parses response to JSON
}
```